# WCF - Channel time out when running app from different machine

Tags: wcf

I am trying to troubleshoot an issue with my app running at a client's site. The app uses WCF to send and retrieve files.
It was running flawlessly but started to show the following error after the client started running from a different machine in the same network:

> **The request channel timed out while waiting for a reply after 00:00:57.6797680. Increase the timeout value passed to the call to
>   Request or increase the SendTimeout value on the Binding. The time
>   allotted to this operation may have been a portion of a longer
>   timeout.**

All timeouts in the config have been increased to 10min and it made no difference.

Unfortunately I cannot run this locally with VS to debug it.

Here's the binding:

```
<customBinding>
  <binding name="MyServiceSoap12">
    <textMessageEncoding maxReadPoolSize="64" maxWritePoolSize="16"
        messageVersion="Soap11WSAddressingAugust2004" writeEncoding="utf-8">
      <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="8192" maxArrayLength="16384"
          maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="16384" />
    </textMessageEncoding>
    <security authenticationMode="UserNameOverTransport" >
      <localClientSettings maxClockSkew="00:10:00"/>
      <localServiceSettings maxClockSkew="00:10:00"/>
      <secureConversationBootstrap>
        <localClientSettings maxClockSkew="00:30:00"/>
        <localServiceSettings maxClockSkew="00:30:00"/>
      </secureConversationBootstrap>
    </security>
    <httpsTransport manualAddressing="false" maxBufferPoolSize="200000000"
        maxReceivedMessageSize="200000000" allowCookies="false" authenticationScheme="Anonymous"
        bypassProxyOnLocal="false" decompressionEnabled="true" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard"
        keepAliveEnabled="true" maxBufferSize="200000000" proxyAuthenticationScheme="Anonymous"
        realm="" transferMode="Buffered" unsafeConnectionNtlmAuthentication="false"
        useDefaultWebProxy="true" requireClientCertificate="false" />
  </binding>
</customBinding>
```

Update: The connectivity to the service is OK - the app runs other service operations without issues, from the same service. One particular operation (that retrieves files) is causing the error.

Where would you start looking?

Thanks!

Comment: `the app uses WCF` - what bindings, config etc? Does the telnet test work from the client machine to the WCF service? turn the firewall off as a *test* only and try again

Comment: Wal, you're right. I posted the binding.

Comment: The connectivity to the service is OK - the app runs other service operations without issues, from the same service. One particular operation is causing the error.

Comment: and the firewall disable test?

Comment: are you sending a large file? did you increase the SendTimeout  attribute? (can't see it in that config). Does sending the file on a different PC on the same network work or do they both fail?

Comment: Wal, please write and answer saying that I did not include the SendTimeout attribute (so I can mark it as correct). I had several other bindings that had this attribute but this one did not have. That was the fix I needed. That was really dumb of my part :)

Comment: done. glad you fixed your issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

are you sending a large file?

did you increase the SendTimeout attribute? (I did not see it in your config)